# html2canvas Black background after background color is specified

Tags: angular, html2canvas

I have an issue with the background color. Let me explain. I have an Angular app (Angular 8), and I have the latest npm package installed. I want to convert one div, that contains a lot of charts (chartjs).
I have the following setup:

```ts
import html2canvas from 'html2canvas';

export class SystemOverviewComponent implements OnInit {
    convertToPdf() {
    
    var elem = document.getElementById('pdfContent');
    elem.style.background = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)';
    var opts = {
      allowTaint: true,
      taintTest: false,
      foreignObjectRendering: true,
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 200, 0, 1)',
      scrollX: -this.pdfContent.nativeElement.offsetLeft, scrollY: 0
    }
    html2canvas(elem, opts).then((canvas) => {
      elem.appendChild(canvas);

      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
      a.download = 'somefile.jpg';
      a.click();
    });
  }
}
```

and the html is like this:

```html
<div class="container-fluid" id="pdfContent" #pdfContent>
   <!-- Some staff here -->
</div>
```

This is how it looks in the browser:
[image: how it should look]
This is how the canvas looks from `elem.appendChild(canvas);`:
[image: on html]
this is how it looks from the export:
[image]
Here we notice not only that the ship is black, but also there is a black area under the end of the canvas.

The code behind the chart and the svg is this:

```html
<div id="chart-div" style="position: relative; z-index: 0; grid-column: 1; grid-row: 2;">
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>

    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 770 155"
        style="position: relative; z-index: 1; grid-column: 1; grid-row: 2; pointer-events: none;">
        <defs>
            <path id="ship"
                d="M479.65,48.343c0-0.686,0-1.516,0-2.188h0.015......0.199" /> <!-- I shortened the path to not clug the screen -->
            <rect id="bg" x="-1%" y="-1%" width="102%" height="102%" fill="transperent" />
            <mask id="myMask">
                <use xlink:href="#bg" fill="white" />
                <use xlink:href="#ship" fill="black" />
            </mask>
        </defs>
        <use xlink:href="#bg" mask="url(#myMask)" fill="white" fill-opacity="1" />
        <use xlink:href="#ship" fill="none" id="ShipRecttangle"
            style="fill:transparent; stroke-width:0.264583;stroke:black;" />
    </svg>
```

Can someone suggest what am I doing wrong?

Best regards,
Julian